# listing prime numbers from user input in java

Tags: java

in java what i am trying to do is have a user input a value greater than 0 and with that number they input list that amount of prime numbers starting from 2

so if the user inputs "3" the program will display 2,3,5
if the user inputs "5" the program will display 2,3,5,7,11
and so on

the problem is I cant figure out how to have the user input do this correctly, i either end up with the numbers repeating however many times or the list ending at the user input, any help would be apreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Primes 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


        int n = console.nextInt();

        if(n<=0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=2; i < 100; i++)
            {
                boolean isPrime = true;

                for(int j=2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if(i%j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(isPrime)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "for(int i=2; i < 100; i++)" Why did you choose 100?

Comment: dont know just a large number to see if it worked

Comment: Related question. When you get the input from the user, what do you do with it?

Comment: This question should be moved to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com and closed there as a dup of: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/efficiently-determining-if-a-number-is-prime

Comment: @alfasin it's not a duplicate of that. The question isn't how to figure out primality quickly, it's a simpler question of how to stop once an exact number of primes has been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a count of how many primes have been found by changing your `for` loop to stop when you've found enough primes and performing `primesFound++` when a prime is found:

```java
    for (int i = 2, primesFound = 0; primesFound < n; i++)
    {
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
       }
       if (isPrime)
       {
           System.out.println(i);
           primesFound++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: @PianoMeow because this code is unnecessarily complicated and difficult to follow. You can make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

I rather have code that is refactored, each method is doing one thing, it makes it much easier to read, debug and maintain.

All we need to do is separate the logic that checks if a number is prime from the logic that goes over the numbers until `n` prime numbers are found:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printNPrimes(5);
}

static private boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static private void printNPrimes(int n) {
    int i = 2;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            System.out.println(i + " is Prime");
            n--;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good refactoring :) Small correction: `i <= Math.sqrt(n)`. Code currently thinks 4 and other primes squared are primes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//prime 

int i,j;

Set<Integer> primeNums = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> notPrimeNums = new HashSet<>();
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

for(i=1; i<fiboList.size(); i++) {
    for(j=i+1; j<fiboList.size(); j++) {
        if( i % j == 0 ) {
            notPrimeNums.add(fiboList.get(i));
        }else {
            primeNums.add(fiboList.get(i));
        }
    }
}

stack.addAll(primeNums);
Collections.sort(stack);
System.out.println("Prime numbers:"+" "+stack);

}
```